# Build cordova apps via ssh on a remote Mac

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, ssh

I've been building Android Phonegap apps locally on my Windows PC and using Phonegap Build to build IOS apps.

The design guys have a Mac that we're already using to publish the app in iTunes.

But even if Phonegap build is a great tool, there are many drawbacks : build time can sometimes be quite long, not all plugins are available, plugins submission seems sometimes quite long and not always successfull, building debugging a home-made plugin using Phonegap build seems just impossible.

For all those reasons I feel the need to build locally also IOS projects and maybe also develop native plugins.

So my idea would be to use ssh to connect to the Designer's Mac and use it to build.

Do other people process in that way? Would it work? Are there things I should be carefull with when installing the CLI, sdk and other tools?

For example I think it would be a good idea to install npm locally in my user I'll use for SSH.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it is possible 
First you need to instal phonegap on Designer's Mac, and enable ssh [image]
Then in your system open terminal/cmd type

```
ssh usernameOfDesignerMac@ipaddress
```

then enter yes,

[image]
 then enter password of that user. thats all now you can access Designer's mac, 
[image]
[image]

```
cd cordovaProjectLocation
sudo cordova build ios/android
```

[image][image][image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I'd like my ssh user to have as less persmissions as possible and access only to some folders, is there a way to install xcode, npm and the cli so I don't need to sudo when using the cli?

Comment: A note for those getting provisioning profile errors: You'll need to move your profiles from 

`/Users/<user>/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/`

to

`/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/`

by copying or linking them. Even if they're in your user folder, xcodebuild won't look in that folder if you're ssh'd as that user.