# How to deploy Cordova app to remote machine?

Tags: linux, node.js, cordova, remote-debugging, visual-studio-code

Good day!
I have some server with nodeJs and i want easy deploy my code to remote machine.

Case: simple netbook with Lubuntu+VisualStudio Code->run->delpoy to server (Ubuntu Server 14.04).
May be some solutions exists?
Thank you!

P.S. possible this may can help? [build cordova by ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711191/build-cordova-apps-via-ssh-on-a-remote-mac)

P.S. i change theme, because old theme is not 100% valid.

Comment: I use [shipit.js](https://github.com/shipitjs/shipit) for my deployment related tasks, would recomend

Comment: You could use Webstorm it has deployment options.